# Pydrive: get details about shared file

Tags: python, pydrive

```
file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "'<folder ID>' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()
```

This gives me details of shared folder through folder id. But I want to get details about a particular shared file

Answer (score 0):

you can loop over the file list and find the relevant file you are looking for

```
for file1 in file_list:
  print('title: %s, id: %s' % (file1['title'], file1['id']))
```

Comment: i want something like when i give "shared file id" as an input it should give me details of file size,title, mimeType,etc.. i dont want to iterate through shared folder.
Basically i need a code where i can get details of shared file using pydrive